# Not able to link CSS file to HTML with Atom text editor, CSS file is in root file on my desktop

Tags: atom-editor

Belo is the code for both HTML and CSS. Not sure what I am doing wrong with link.

```css
nav {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es"
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="style" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  <title> mine</title>
</head>

<nav>
Some Day
</nav>

<html>
```

Comment: It's a path problem. Provide relative path in href

Answer (score 0):

Try linking relatively like this:

```
<link rel="style" type="text/css" href="../style.css"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="style" type="text/css" href="/style.css"/>
```